# telerik treeview control upgrade issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, treeview

I recently updated telerik controls on a website. Earlier I was using Telerik.WebControls.RadTreeNodeEventArgs but now I'm using Telerik.web.ui.RadTreeNodeEventArgs.

Now my problem is when I change the telerik.webcontrol to telerik.web.ui .............this "e.NodeClicked" property starts showing an error saying that it does not have any property like that. Now I have to update this control but I'm stuck at e.NodeClicked.... So please guys help me out by suggesting some other property which replace this one.

```
protected void rtvTopLeftPatientMenu_NodeClick(object o, Telerik.WebControls.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
```

{

```
   if (e.NodeClicked.Parent != null)
   {
       Session["NodeClicked"] = e.NodeClicked.Parent.Value;
       try
       {
           if (e.NodeClicked.Parent.Parent.Value != null)
           {
               Session["NodeClicked"] = e.NodeClicked.Parent.Parent.Value;
           }
       }
       catch { };
   }
```

Comment: Where is WPF in this question? Removed tag.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work with the latest release of RadTreeView for ASP.NET Ajax. The NodeClicked property was part of RadTreeView classic. If you are using the up-to-date version you should use the e.Node property.

Comment: Can u change the above code using e.node..  I have many pages which are having quite lengthy code... I don't know how i change them.